# A fireman is firing at a distant target and has only $10\%$ chance of hitting it...

Tags: probability

A fireman is firing at a distant target and has a $10\%$ chance of hitting it. What is the number of rounds he must fire in order to have at least a $50\%$ chance of hitting the target at least once

I have no idea how to attempt this percentage type question. Can anybody please provide any suggestions on this question?

Any effort will be appreciatable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... as typical, what have you tried?

Comment: `A fireman is firing` Not that it matters much math-wise, but that's not what a [*fireman*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fireman) typically does. The duplicate question has it better by calling it a "shooter".

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a type of counting called **complementary counting**. It is basically counting the *opposite* of what you are trying to count. In this case, what is the opposite of counting at least $1?$

I don't want to give any further hints since there seems to be no attempt to solve the problem. Also, [this is a practically same question on MSE that has been answered.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363354/what-is-the-number-of-times-shooter-needs-to-fire) Please search for duplicates before posting a question.